# Pig game - Roll the dice

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, random, dice

Currently the dice image will change after I click the button "Click to roll the die".
And I also want to update the label "Player's total" when I click the "Click to roll the dice" bottom.

How do I achieve this?

```
private void rollDieBotton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RollDice();
}       

private void RollDice() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++)
        dice[i] = roll.Next(1, 6);

    dicePictureBox.Image = diceImages[dice[0]];
}

private void PigForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    diceImages = new Image[6];
    diceImages[0] = Properties.Resources.Alea_1;
    diceImages[1] = Properties.Resources.Alea_2;
    diceImages[2] = Properties.Resources.Alea_3;
    diceImages[3] = Properties.Resources.Alea_4;
    diceImages[4] = Properties.Resources.Alea_5;
    diceImages[5] = Properties.Resources.Alea_6;

    dice = new int[1] { 0 };

    roll = new Random();
}
```

Comment: You want to sum up the dice results and present them to the user?

Comment: Hey chrfin !! Yes I want to sum up the dice results once I clicked the "rolldiebotton" and present them to the user

Comment: Just a small note - the call to the `Random` instance that you're using, `roll.Next(1, 6)`, will only return numbers from 1 to 5. The second parameter is an "exclusive" upper bound. If you want numbers from 1 to 6 you need t call it as `roll.Next(1, 7)`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Got it !! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `dice` value to sum the rolls instead of just store the current roll and do something like:

```
private void RollDice() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++)
    {
        var currenRoll = roll.Next(1, 6);
        dice[i] += currentRoll;
        dicePictureBox.Image = diceImages[currentRoll];

        playerTotalLabel.Text = String.Format("Total: {0}", dice[i]);
    }
}
```